# Unity3D Custom Shader Prevent Light Addition?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I've used Unity Projectors and a custom shader to create the effect of a custom image shape coming from a projector. It works great except if the light from the projector comes into contact with the light from another copy of the project, the light colors are combined. I don't want this to happen, so if i specify green for example for both projectors, and the light comes into contact with each other, the light should overlap and remain green for both projectors. Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

I'm new to shaders and found this shader online. Any help on how I could modify the shader to accomplish my goal would be much appreciated. Or if there is another way to accomplish this goal would be great. I tried putting each projector into a layer and tell each to ignore that layer when projecting their light, but this had no effect. Thanks.

```
Shader "Custom/MyProjectorShader" {
Properties{
    _Color("Tint Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _Attenuation("Falloff", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 1.0
    _ShadowTex("Cookie", 2D) = "gray" {}
}
Subshader{
    Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" }
    Pass{
        ZWrite Off
        ColorMask RGB
        Blend SrcAlpha One // Additive blending
        Offset -1, -1

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct v2f {
            float4 uvShadow : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        };

        float4x4 unity_Projector;
        float4x4 unity_ProjectorClip;

        v2f vert(float4 vertex : POSITION)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(vertex);
            o.uvShadow = mul(unity_Projector, vertex);
            return o;
        }

        sampler2D _ShadowTex;
        fixed4 _Color;
        float _Attenuation;

        fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            // Apply alpha mask
            fixed4 texCookie = tex2Dproj(_ShadowTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.uvShadow));
            fixed4 outColor = _Color * texCookie.a;
            // Attenuation
            float depth = i.uvShadow.z; // [-1 (near), 1 (far)]
            return outColor * clamp(1.0 - abs(depth) + _Attenuation, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
```

Unlike what the comment says, `Blend One One` is the regular Additive (Linear Dodge) blend mode. Using this new blend mode you'll need to make sure your textures have an alpha channel too.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Blend.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably `Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha` would work better in this case because it would also avoid so remaining border cutout.